# What is the first variables of my stack program?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, callstack

I have started the assembly.

I don't understand why I have two variables before argc.

[image: Image of Stack]

What is the 0000 and the 0008 ?

```
global _main

section .text
_main:
    ; write
    mov rax, 0x2000004
    mov rdi, 0x1
    mov rsi, [rsp+24]
    mov rdx, 3
    syscall

    ; return (0)
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    mov rdi, 0x0
    syscall
```

I'm on macOSX Mojave and I compile with:

```
nasm -f macho64 ex01.s && ld -macosx_version_min 10.14 -lSystem ex01.o
```

Comment: What is the 0000 and the 0008? Your `argv` is an array of pointers with a sentinel `NULL` after the last argument. `argv` always contains the executable name (`argv[0]`) and since no additional arguments were passed, `argv[1]` will be `NULL`.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0, which illustrates `_start` setting up some parameters and calling `_main`.  You might try to find the  particular `_start` that is being used in your environment to see how `_main` is being called.  My guess is that +0 is a return address for `_start`.

Comment: Do not post pictures of terminal output.  Instead, post this output as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're targetting modern MacOS, hence `ld` will emit dyld assisted `LC_MAIN` load command for entry point handling.
The `[rsp]` is the return address to libdyld `_start` function epilogue:

```
mov        edi, eax ; pass your process return code as 1st argument under System V 64bit ABI
call       exit ;from libSystem
hlt
```

What it means you don't need to exit your process through a system call like you do in:

```
; return (0)
mov rax, 0x2000001
mov rdi, 0x0
syscall
```

Instead:

```
xor eax,eax
ret
```

is enough (and that's what compilers will emit btw).

Your buffer will also get flushed in the `ret` / `libdyld` approach. That's irrelevant for your system write call you are doing, but could be for a `printf` for instance.

Here's a great [article](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2019/5/13/exploring-startup-implementations-os-x) that describes lots of details.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why I have two variables before argc.

**You wrote a `main`, not a `_start`.**  The stack space above your return address is "not yours"; there's no standard for how much stack space the CRT startup code uses before calling main, or what it leaves on the stack between the argc/argv/env and the call to `main`.

In `main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`, you'll find `argc` in EDI, a pointer to `argv[]` is in RSI, and a pointer to `envp[]` in RDX.

But we can look and see what's there to reverse-engineer `main`'s caller:

---

The numbers starting with `0000` are byte offsets relative to RSP.  Whatever generated your image is dumping and analyzing 8-byte stack "slots" as integers, and as pointers if they point to valid memory.

All this stuff on the stack got there by the `_start` code that calls `main` putting it there, or the kernel putting it there before entering user-space.

- `[rsp + 0]` has `main`'s return address, so it points to code.  Presumably `_start` called your main with code like `call main` / `mov edi, eax` / `call exit` to pass your return-value to `exit()` if `main` returns (which yours doesn't). So it makes sense that your return address is pointing at a `mov edi, eax`.
- `0` is probably a frame-pointer sentinel, for the benefit of code that's compiled with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` being able to back-trace a chain of saved-RBP values.  Pushing a `0` in `_start` terminates that linked list, if the caller then does `mov rbp, rsp` so a `push rbp` in its callee will push a pointer to that terminator.  The x86-64 System V ABI doc suggests doing this.

The rest of the entries look exactly like the entry-to-user-space state of the stack at `_start`

- `1` = `argc` means you ran the program with no args, so the shell passed 1 implicit first arg (the program name, `argv[0]`).
- then a NULL-terminated `argv[]` (not a *pointer* to argv, the actual array is right there on the stack).  The first element is a pointer to the string holding the path to your executable, because your caller chose to pass that to `execve()` as per usual
- then a NULL-terminated `envp[]` array.  Again not `char **envp` but the actual array by value.  Each entry is a `char*` to an entry in the environment.

Again, the x86-64 System V ABI documents this stack layout.  MacOS follows the x86-64 System V ABI.  https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI

---

(I'm surprised about stack alignment though.  On Linux RSP is 16-byte aligned on entry to user-space; it's not a function and isn't `call`ed so there's no return value on the stack.  So `argc` is 16-byte aligned.  But here, your code seems to show that `rsp` in `main` has the same alignment as `argc`.  That would mean `main`'s caller had the stack 8 bytes away from 16-byte alignment before the `call`.  Maybe that's what OS X always does?)