# On x64 Linux, what is the difference between syscall, int 0x80 and ret to exit a program?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, exit

I decided yesterday to learn assembly (NASM syntax) after years of C++ and Python and I'm already confused about the way to exit a program. It's mostly about ret because it's the suggested instruction on SASM IDE.

I'm speaking for main obviously. I don't care about x86 backward compatibility. Only the x64 Linux best way. I'm curious.

Comment: When you return from `main()`, the standard runtime library calls the `exit()` system call, so I think they're equivalent.

Comment: If you are using the C library, as is hinted by `main`, then you should not use a system call. The simplest is to `ret`. You can also `call exit` which is useful from deeper in the call stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If you use `printf` or other libc functions, it's best to `ret` from main or `call exit`.**  (Which are equivalent; main's caller will call the libc `exit` function.)

If not, if you were only making other raw system calls like `write` with `syscall`, it's also appropriate and consistent to exit that way, but either way, or `call exit` are 100% fine in main.

If you want to work without libc at all, e.g. put your code under `_start:` instead of `main:` and link with `ld` or `gcc -static -nostdlib`, then you can't use `ret`.  Use `mov eax, 231` (__NR_exit_group) / `syscall`.

`main` is a real & normal function like any other (called with a valid return address), but `_start` (the process entry point) isn't.  On entry to `_start`, the stack holds `argc` and `argv`, so trying to `ret` would set RIP=argc, and then code-fetch would segfault on that unmapped address.  [Nasm segmentation fault on RET in _start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760002/nasm-segmentation-fault-on-ret-in-start)

---

#### System call vs. ret-from-main

Exiting via a system call is like calling `_exit()` in C - **skip** `atexit()` and libc cleanup, notably not **flushing any buffered stdout output** (line buffered on a terminal, full-buffered otherwise).
This leads to symptoms such as [Using printf in assembly leads to empty output when piping, but works on the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379553/using-printf-in-assembly-leads-to-empty-output-when-piping-but-works-on-the-ter) (or if your output doesn't end with `\n`, even on a terminal.)

`main` is a function, called (indirectly) from CRT startup code.  (Assuming you link your program normally, like you would a C program.) Your hand-written main works exactly like a compiler-generate C `main` function would.  Its caller (`__libc_start_main`) really does do something like `int result = main(argc, argv); exit(result);`,
e.g. `call rax` (pointer passed by `_start`) / `mov edi, eax` / `call exit`.
So returning from main is exactly<sup>1</sup> like calling `exit`.

- [Syscall implementation of exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit) for a comparison of the relevant C functions, `exit` vs. `_exit` vs. `exit_group` and the underlying asm system calls.
- C question: [What is the difference between exit and return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463551/what-is-the-difference-between-exit-and-return) is primarily about `exit()` vs. `return`, although there is mention of calling `_exit()` directly, i.e. just making a system call.  It's applicable because C main compiles to an asm main just like you'd write by hand.

**Footnote 1:** You can invent a hypothetical intentionally weird case where it's different. e.g. you used stack space in `main` as your stdio buffer with `sub rsp, 1024` / `mov rsi, rsp` / ... / [`call setvbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf).  Then returning from main would involve putting RSP above that buffer, and __libc_start_main's call to exit could overwrite some of that buffer with return addresses and locals before execution reached the fflush cleanup.  This mistake is more obvious in asm than C because you need `leave` or `mov rsp, rbp` or `add rsp, 1024` or something to point RSP at your return address.

In C++, return from main runs destructors for its locals (before global/static exit stuff), `exit` doesn't.  But that just means the compiler makes asm that does more stuff before actually running the `ret`, so it's all manual in asm, like in C.

The other difference is of course the asm / calling-convention details: exit status in EAX (return value) or EDI (first arg), and of course to `ret` you have to have RSP pointing at your return address, like it was on function entry.  With `call exit` you don't, and you can even do a conditional tailcall of exit like `jne exit`.  Since it's a noreturn function, you don't really need RSP pointing at a valid return address.  (RSP [should be aligned by 16 before a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070716/glibc-scanf-segmentation-faults-when-called-from-a-function-that-doesnt-align-r), though, or RSP%16 = 8 before a tailcall, matching the alignment after call pushes a return address.  It's unlikely that exit / fflush cleanup will do any alignment-required stores/loads to the stack, but it's a good habit to get this right.)

(This whole footnote is about `ret` vs. `call exit`, not `syscall`, so it's a bit of a tangent from the rest of the answer.  You can also run `syscall` without caring where the stack-pointer points.)

---

#### `SYS_exit` vs. `SYS_exit_group` raw system calls

The raw `SYS_exit` system call is for exiting the *current thread*, like `pthread_exit()`.
(eax=60 / `syscall`, or eax=1 / `int 0x80`).

`SYS_exit_group` is for exiting the *whole program*, like `_exit`.
(eax=231 / `syscall`, or eax=252 / `int 0x80`).

In a single-threaded program you *can* use either, but conceptually exit_group makes more sense to me if you're going to use raw system calls.  glibc's `_exit()` wrapper function actually uses the `exit_group` system call (since glibc 2.3).  See [Syscall implementation of exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit) for more details.

However, nearly all the hand-written asm you'll ever see uses `SYS_exit`<sup>1</sup>.  It's not "wrong", and `SYS_exit` is perfectly acceptable for a program that didn't start more threads.  Especially if you're trying to save code size with `xor eax,eax` / `inc eax` (3 bytes in 32-bit mode) or `push 60` / `pop rax` (3 bytes in 64-bit mode), while `push 231`/`pop rax` would be even larger than `mov eax,231` because it doesn't fit in a signed imm8.

Note 1:  (Usually actually hard-coding the number, not using `__NR_`... constants from `asm/unistd.h` or their `SYS_`... names from `sys/syscall.h`)

And historically, it's all there was.  Note that in unistd_32.h, `__NR_exit` has call number 1, but `__NR_exit_group` = 252 wasn't added until years later when the kernel gained support for tasks that share virtual address space with their parent, aka threads started by `clone(2)`.  This is when `SYS_exit` conceptually became "exit current thread".  (But one could easily and convincingly argue that in a single-threaded program, `SYS_exit` *does* still mean exit the whole program, because it only differs from `exit_group` if there are multiple threads.)

To be honest, I've never used eax=252 / int 0x80 in anything, only ever eax=1. It's only in 64-bit code where I often use `mov eax,231` instead of `mov eax,60` because neither number is "simple" or memorable the way 1 is, so might as well be a cool guy and use the "modern" `exit_group` way in my single-threaded toy program / experiment / microbenchmark / SO answer. :P  (If I didn't enjoy tilting at windmills, I wouldn't spend so much time on assembly, especially on SO.)

And BTW, I usually use NASM for one-off experiments so it's inconvenient to use pre-defined symbolic constants for call numbers; with GCC to preprocess a `.S` before running GAS you can make your code self-documenting with `#include <sys/syscall.h>` so you can use `mov $SYS_exit_group, %eax` (or `$__NR_exit_group`), or `mov eax, __NR_exit_group` with `.intel_syntax noprefix`.

---

#### Don't use the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI in 64-bit code:

[What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code) explains what happens if you use the COMPAT_IA32_EMULATION `int 0x80` ABI in 64-bit code.

It's totally fine for just exiting, as long as your kernel has that support compiled in, otherwise it will segfault just like any other random int number like `int 0x7f`.  (e.g. on WSL1, or people that built custom kernels and disabled that support.)

But the only reason you'd do it that way in asm would be so you could build the same source file with `nasm -felf32` or `nasm -felf64`.  (You can't use `syscall` in 32-bit code, except on some AMD CPUs which have a 32-bit version of `syscall`.  And the 32-bit ABI uses different call numbers anyway so this wouldn't let the same source be useful for both modes.)

---

Related:

- [Why am I allowed to exit main using ret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59678635/why-am-i-allowed-to-exit-main-using-ret/59687088#59687088) (CRT startup code calls main, you're not returning *directly* to the kernel.)
- [Nasm segmentation fault on RET in _start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760002/nasm-segmentation-fault-on-ret-in-start) - you can't `ret` from `_start`
- [Using printf in assembly leads to empty output when piping, but works on the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379553/using-printf-in-assembly-leads-to-empty-output-when-piping-but-works-on-the-ter) stdout buffer (not) flushing with raw system call exit
- [Syscall implementation of exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit) `call exit` vs. `mov eax,60`/`syscall` (_exit) vs. `mov eax,231`/`syscall` (exit_group).
- [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code/52131094#52131094) - modern Linux distros config GCC in a way that `call exit` or `call puts` won't link with `nasm -felf64 foo.asm` && `gcc foo.o`.
- [Is main() really start of a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783404/is-main-really-start-of-a-c-program/64116561#64116561) - Ciro's answer is a deep dive into how glibc + its CRT startup code actually call main (including x86-64 asm disassembly in GDB), and shows the glibc source code for __libc_start_main.
- [Linux x86 Program Start Up
  or - How the heck do we get to main()?](https://web.archive.org/web/20191210114310/http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) 32-bit asm, and more detail than you'll probably want until you're a lot more comfortable with asm, but if you've ever wondered why CRT runs so much code before getting to main, that covers what's happening at a level that's a couple steps up from using GDB with `starti` (stop at the process entry point, e.g. in the dynamic linker's `_start`) and `stepi` until you get to your own `_start` or `main`.
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info lots of good links about this and everything else.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it's clearer in my mind. I prefer to start on good bases.

Comment: @SepRoland: Thanks, fixed.  (Feel free to fix typos yourself if you want; although in this case I ended up making a couple more tweaks).

Comment: I'll remember, although I think there might be other people that really dislike having their text fixed...

Comment: @SepRoland: I certainly appreciate people tidying up editing mistakes in my answers, like typos or a repeated word, or a sentence I started one way, then went back and rephrased without fully removing the old words.  People that object even to typo fixes that don't change phrasing / meaning are IMO missing the point of Stack Overflow (creating a library of useful answers).  IMO leaving comments instead of editing is a valid choice when the answer is actually wrong (e.g. phrasing implies something incorrect about cases other than the one being asked about).  People can always roll back, though.

Comment: Nice answer! But why use `exit_group`? In my experience (unless done during an unrecoverable, unexpected, error) this is always a code smell. If one has multiple threads, either one joins them before calling `exit` or explicitly marks them detached (a.k.a. "daemon threads" in Java/Python) so they are automatically killed by `exit`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: The `exit_group` system call is how processes normally exit, via `exit(3)`.  Even `_exit(2)` uses `SYS_exit_group` in glibc2.3 and later ([Syscall implementation of exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46903180)), so I assumed SYS_exit was essentially considered obsolete, and/or that `exit_group` is the normal way to exit.  I guess `pthread_exit` would use SYS_exit, unless threads have some other way of exiting.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: but `pthread_exit` isn't just a syscall wrapper; it does some cleanup.  And if this is the last thread, then it runs exit(3) -> SYS_exit_group.  But if not, then yes I guess it would run SYS_exit.  So AFAIK, glibc doesn't have a wrapper function for SYS_exit, only an eventual use inside pthreads. Your argument that it's a bad idea to intentionally use exit_group to kill other threads, but accidentally leaving them running in case of bugs is even worse. Moot point in a single-threaded simple toy program, so it's more of a "remember this is what glibc does" thing.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't know `exit` used `exit_group`, I stand corrected :)